# Enable SSL on Facebook SDK event flushing

Tags: c#, objective-c, https, xamarin, ios9

## Situation

Making our app ready for iOS 9 showed up problems with HTTP calls, resulting in following errors appearing periodically in 15s intervals on the application log:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

This appears to be the case because Facebook SDK app events are flushed periodically as stated by the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAppEvents)...

> **Events are** not sent immediately when logged. They're **cached and flushed** out to the Facebook servers in a number of situations:
>   when an event count threshold is passed (currently 100 logged events).
>   **when a time threshold is passed (currently 15 seconds).**
>   when an app has gone to background and is then brought back to the foreground.

Deactivating the `AppEvents.ActivateApp ();` disabled the log messages, so this is definitely the source.

This problem seems to arise because the Facebook SDK doesn't deliver the app events using SSL. Because adding these lines into the info.plist as stated [here](https://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile/issues/273) and [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/5857#5857) fixed the issue somewhat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!-- ... -->
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
    <dict>  
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
    </dict> 
 </dict>
</plist>
```

On the other hand this makes the app just use HTTP.

## Workaround

The [Xamarin documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/) states to add an exception DOMAIN instead of opening the app for arbritary loads.

> Note: **If your application requires a connection to an insecure website, you should always enter the domain as an exception** using NSExceptionDomains instead of turning ATS off completely using NSAllowsArbitraryLoads. NSAllowsArbitraryLoads should only be used in extreme emergency situations.

I tried to add this piece of code into the info.plist but without success. Speaking the error message persists.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>{DOMAIN}</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionsAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But what would be the DOMAIN in this case? We tried; `www.facebook.com` and `facebook.com`. It would be preferable to activate SSL for the Facebook SDK instead, but if this isn't possible adding an exception Domain would be a valid workaround as well.

## Question

Is it possible to make the Facebook SDK use SSL and if so, how? Screening the documentation didn't bring any results on this behalf. Maybe we're searching the wrong terms on our search engines, any suggestions?

## Note

We are currently using the Facebook SDK Xamarin component in version 4.5.1.